# MDL select list

Tags: angular2-mdl

I am making a select list input type. Although the data which need to be there in the options are there, but I am not able to select the option. As in it is not showing the selected input type. Below mention is the code to it. Please help:

```
 <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select getmdl-select__fullwidth">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1" value="" readonly tabIndex="-1">

                    <label for="sample1" class="mdl-textfield__label">Type Of Organisation*</label>
                    <ul for="sample1" class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu">
                          <li class="mdl-menu__item">School</li>
                          <li class="mdl-menu__item">College</li>
                          <li class="mdl-menu__item">University</li>
                          <li class="mdl-menu__item">Training Company</li>
                          <li class="mdl-menu__item">Training Institute</li>
                    </ul>




        </div>
```

Below is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: how is your question related to angular2-mdl?

Comment: Actually I am using MDL in angular 2. Otherwise my question was strictly on failure in showing the selected options. ANyways thanks for considering this question. BTW I am able to figure out this few days back. Anyways thanks.